# How can I pass in operations to make on a method parameter via a custom aspectJ annotation?

Tags: java, aspectj

It is non-spring and operationsToDo needs to be able to handle any operations on the first parameter. I need to be able to do operationsToDo from the annotation on param. See below code example

Annotation example A:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation(operationsToDo=".getIdentity().getUsername()")
public Int getHighScore(User user, Game game) {
    ...
}
```

Annotation example B:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation(operationsToDo=".getEmail().get(0).getSubject()")
public List<Cat> getUsersCats(User user) {
    ...
}
```

Aspect File:

```
@Aspect
class MyCustomAspect {
    @Around(value = "@annotation(myCustomAnnotation)", argNames = "joinPoint,myCustomAnnotation")
    public Object getData(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyCustomAnnotation myCustomAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        Object param = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        String something = *Do operationsToDo on param*;
        System.out.println(something);
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback. Either accept the answer or ask a follow-up question, please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just write code into a text constant as an annotation parameter and expect it to magically get compiled and executed in a language like Java. This just is not how it works. Please change your application design and use a design pattern better suited to solving your problem.

It would be easy to get a reference to the annotation and its parameter value in AspectJ, but that does not give you compiled and executable code.